# Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space - notation and basics

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I am reading about Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space (RKHS) while reading through Functional Analysis and Hilbert Space material and I am unable to understand the notation: $K(\cdot,x_i)$. What does the dot '.' signify? $K$ is a positive semi-definite kernel and $x_i$ is a point in real space.  I have a background in linear algebra, statistics and advanced calculus.

Answer (score 4):

The dot is a place holder for an appropriate variable. You may have seen this before when denoting inner products $ \| \cdot \|$.

Comment: So, is $k(·,xi)$ a vector, with the placeholder taking all the elements in a vector $x$ other than $x_i$?

Comment: @qlinck $K_x := K(\cdot, x_i)$ is a function (which may be a vector of an appropriate vector space). The placeholder can take any value in $X$. More precisely, if the domain of $K$ is $X \times X$, then $x$ can be any element of $X$. This sort of thing is pretty common in multivariable stuff; e.g., taking a function $f: X\times Y \to Z$ and considering another function $F_x: X \to Z$ which fixes a value for the second (or first) entry.