# reproducing kernel hilbert space notation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, inner-products, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

I'm trying to understand reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces (RKHSs) from scientific papers, however I don't find any gentle introduction. However, my main problem, at the moment, seems to be to understand the used notation. I understand that a kernel $k$ is a function which maps features to the respective inner product in a Hilbert space, i.e. $k(x,z)=<\phi(x), \phi(z)>_H$ with $\phi$ mapping from the original space to an Hilbert space. However, what I don't understand is the $(\cdot)$  notation, e.g. $k(\cdot, z)$. What means the dot instead of the first argument? In several papers I read something like $k(\cdot, z)=\phi(z)$ but what is the meaning of this? Intuitively I would think something like this: $\forall x, k(x, z)=\phi(z)$, but it does not seem to make any sense to me... Also the following answer [Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space - notation and basics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183888/reproducing-kernel-hilbert-space-notation-and-basics) does not clarify my doubts... So, what is the real meaning of $\cdot$? Does anyone know any clear introduction on this topic?

Comment: $k(\cdot,z)$ refers to the function $$x\mapsto k(x,z)$$

Comment: so $k(\cdot,z)= \phi(z) \Leftrightarrow \forall x, k(x,z) = \phi(z)$? But in this manner $k(x,z)$ is not $<\phi(x), \phi(z)>$ ...

Comment: @volperossa: What Ruy is saying is that is  $k(.,z)$ is just a short hand notation for  $x \rightarrow k(x,z) $ so it just means $ < \phi(x), \phi(z) > $  for any $x$ rather than a specific $x$.

Comment: so what is the meaning of $k(\cdot, z)=\phi(z)$?